# what happens if we pass threads in executorService execute call in Java multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading

See these two examples:

**EXAMPLE 1**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //work
                for (int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++){
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        executorService.execute(thread1);
        executeService.shutdown();
}
```

**EXAMPLE 2**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

        executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //work
                for (int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++){
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        executeService.shutdown();
    }
```

Results are the same in both cases but a friend of mine from StackOverflow [alexei-kaigorodov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1206301/alexei-kaigorodov) ([in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64259108/java-multithreading-is-slow-while-creating-objects-of-a-class-in-android)) said in a comment that

*"executorService is an alternative to treads. There is no sense to put threads in executorService. First, create Runnable, and then either put it as a parameter to a thread and start that thread or submit that runnable to an executorService."*

I hope I am clear with my question, so please tell me the difference in passing runnable to ExecuteService vs. passing thread to ExecutableService.

Comment: In your example you don't start the Thread, so it's not doing anything special. In your example it's just a normal object implementing a `Runnable` type with a`run()` method that the ExecutorSevice will call.

Comment: `Thread` implements `Runnable`, so the executor will simply execute its `run` method, not any other `Thread` specific one (and `Thread#run` simply delegates to the given `Runnable`). Meaning, yes, your friend is right :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Thread implements Runnable` so the excutor service will accept it as a simple `Runnable`, and thus calls the `Thread.run()` method.

Which means that the `Thread` itself will never be started, unless you call its `start()` method yourself, in which case the result is definetely undefined.

So you could say the snippets behave the same, you're only passing a `Runnable` to the `ExecutorService` and that then executes it by calling the `Runnable.run()` method.

Comment: it means that the work is done in main thread only?

Comment: @VijayJangid that is up to the `ExecutorService`-implementation to decide

Comment: @VijayJangid in both cases, the work is done in the executor service on its own threads. In both cases, the Runnable is executed. But when you submit a thread, you wrap that Runnable with a Thread object, which only wastes its memory and  adds nothing to the functionality of Runnable.